# Silent Push notification when app is killed

Tags: ios, ios7, apple-push-notifications, ios9

[image]

I want to update status/flag without calling web service, so i implemented silent push but if app is killed then silent push will not updating my status/flag. Please tell me the other way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is killed, there is nothing you can do about that situation. Push will come through, but it won't automatically start the app and if its a silent push, well then you have zero chance of getting that app to start back up.

You can do one last call to a web service just before the app gets terminated - but you have seconds to do it, so not ideal.